# Infinite scrolling slideshow with inline-blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So most probably there's only some of my code that is wrong. I've been trying for quite a few hours to get it right, so now I'm turning my faith to the loyal people of the interwebs! ;)

So what I'm trying to do is move the leftmost object in the container outside of the screen and then append to the last item in the container to make it seem like it's forever scrolling. As of right now I only have 3 elements to clearly see if it works. What am I doing wrong?

My html:

```
<section class="photo-grid-slideshow">
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>I wanna
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>Dance
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza3.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-crop">
        <h3>With you
            <div class="xs-spacer"></div>
            <a class="med-btn btn-white">Read more</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My css:

```
.photo-crop {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    text-align: left;
}

.photo-grid-slideshow {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #444;
}
```

My javascript:

```
 $(function () {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $(".photo-crop:first-child").animate({marginLeft: '-=33vw'}, 2000, "linear", function() {
            $('this').Css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-crop:last-child');
        });
    }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: try with `appendTo('.photo-crop')` instead `appendTo('.photo-crop:last-child')`

Comment: @NeelShah Not the problem it seems like :(

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$(function() {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $(".photo-crop:first-child").animate({
      marginLeft: '-=33vw'
    }, 2000, "linear", function() {
      $(this).css("margin-left", 0).appendTo('.photo-crop:last-child');
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't work. I almost got it to work now. It seems like theyre are moving properly but the animation won't show and it all stops working on hover. XD

Code: http://pastebin.com/WbDTN2jA